# Conversation service error in the middle of the conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

The conversation service gives an error in the middle of the conversation as shown in the image.
The conversation service is taken from the sample car dashboard [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard) The conversation works quite alright but sometimes it throws this error.I checked the status but its all fine.
[image]

If I try in the conversation service tool, there is no such error.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesnt happen inside the tooling, then it must be something going on in your application. What application are you using? One of our samples?

Comment: Yes, using the car dashboard sample.https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard/

Comment: Also the sample car dashboard STT doesn't work in the demo itself .Why is that?

Comment: Did you deploy your own version of the app and are Seekng errors? Or are you referring to our hosted version? We have been making updates over the last day or two that may have caused this error if you were chatting during an update.

Comment: As for speech, it looks like we broke the connection during the update, I'll make sure we work on that shortly.

Comment: We used the same sample application and the only change was adding a different workspace id?It is safe to say that this is because of the update?Is the updates done? since I tested it now and still get the mentioned error.

Comment: That update would not cause that error for your instance. If you changed the workspace Id you also have to change the conversation service credentials. Did you do that as well?

Comment: Yes. I did that as well.The conversation service works but in the middle of the conversation the mentioned error occurs.

Comment: does it happen at the same spot every single time? or its intermittent? i have never seen this before, can you email me your workspace_id and an approximate time this happened so we can look at the logs. It may not be in the logs becuase it looks like it never hit the service, but without being able to reproduce its hard to say. How many times has it happened?
my email is mmason@us.ibm.com

Comment: Mailed you the details.This doesn't necessarily happen in the same spot every time. It happens when usually every time I run the application.On rare occurrence there is no error. i think this issue came after the updates.